# How to use resources (fonts, images, styles) from external library

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I'm having problems with loading resources (images, font families, styles) from an external resource dll. I would like to have all resources (images, fonts, styles...) in one resource dll and set them to be accessible over all projects (libraries) in this solution. Those projects in solution are different libraries that are referenced and called by main application.

So far i tried several different propositions how to do it but none of them work.
I'm using Visual studio 2019 and compiling for .net 4.6.2 - if that means something...

First I created an resource library called myapp.resources. Inside this project I have a folder named Fonts and inside that folder is the Lato-Thin font.

Also at the root of the project I created a resource dictionary called Fonts.xaml

-Project
    -Fonts
       -Lato-Thin.ttf
    -Fonts.xaml

the structure of the Fonts.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myapp.resources">

    <FontFamily x:Key="LatoThin">Fonts/#Lato Thin</FontFamily>    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In the main app App.xaml I added the loading of that ResourceDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dict">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/myapp.resources;component/Fonts.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

The last step is adding this fontfamily to label control:

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="some random text for test" FontFamily="{StaticResource ResourceKey=LatoThin}"/>
```

But I always get the error that the LatoThin font resource can't be located.

The same error I get with any other resource type like images, styles.

Of course I added the references to projects and every file is where it should be.

The only thing that is working is, for example adding image to buttons in this way.

```
<syncfusion:ButtonAdv x:Name="btnSelectFile" 
                              Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center" SizeMode="Small"
                              Height="26" Width="26" Label="Button" Margin="3,3,3,3"
                        SmallIcon="pack://application:,,,/myapp.resources;component/Images/add.png"/>
```

I tried to find some complete tutorials to follow but I always have the same error.

So, my question would be: How to solve this?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your font file (Lato-Thin.ttf) has its build action set to `Resource`.

In your Fonts.xaml make sure to use this format:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myapp.resources">

    <FontFamily x:Key="LatoThin">/myapp.resources;component/Fonts/#Lato Thin</FontFamily>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Tip: You can remove `pack://application:,,,` from your URIs to make them shorter.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer but still nothing. The app does not give any error but still the labels are showing with default fonts. I tried in several places to set the FontFamily property but nothing changes. Even at design time, if I'm not wrong, intellisense will show the font family, or not? Because, if I recall corectly, after frist rebuild intellisense should show the font name but does not showing anything when  I'm typing in xaml at FontFamily=""...